# D3js multiple parent nodes

Tags: d3.js

I am experimenting with d3 and tree layout. I think if it is possible to create tree with for example two roots. I know that it is rule that tree has only one root but maybe someone has some example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ob0drfk/1/) showing what I think you're looking for. The important code is right near the bottom.

```
node.each(function(d){
if (d.name == "flare") 
    d3.select(this).remove();});
link.each(function(d){
if (d.source.name == "flare") 
    d3.select(this).remove();});
```

This is just using the sample data from one of the d3 tree examples, where the root node has the field `name` as `flare`. Adjust accordingly for your own data set, as well as the name of the `node` and `link` variables (containing the `g` and `path` objects respectively). Essentially how this is works is by creating a tree with a single root node and then removing that node and its links which leaves the children, allowing for as many pseudo-roots as you want.