# How can I rotate a dendrogramm (tree diagram)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, dendrogram

I would like to create a tree diagram (or often called Dendrogram) like descriped here: http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8323795.

Two questions:

1. How can I rotate it 180 degrees (Diagram should go from right to left)?
2. Is it possible to start off with 3 nodes at level 0 (Three starting nodes instead of one)?

I would highly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at these questions and their answers. You might find just what you are looking for.

**About the rotation :**

How to change orientation of a D3 tree layout by 90 degrees:
[How to change orientation of a D3 tree layout by 90 degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099430/how-to-change-orientation-of-a-d3-tree-layout-by-90-degrees?rq=1)

Here's a example :
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3184089

**About the 3 nodes at level 0:**

D3js multiple parent nodes:
[D3js multiple parent nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31185651/d3js-multiple-parent-nodes)